# How to get the value of a Date input?

Tags: javascript

I want to push the modified value of this input in to an array ? when I blur out of it is this possible without making a form and submitting it ?

```js
let input = document.getElementById('date-input')
let arr = []
arr.push(input.value)
```

```html
<input id='date-input' type="date" value="">
```

Comment: Refer here - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_date_value.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you can do that. Check the working code here:

```
let input = document.getElementById('date-input')
let arr = [];
input.addEventListener('blur', addElementValues);
function addElementValues(){
     arr.push(this.value);
      console.log("Arr",arr)
 }
```

Screenshot of the output:
[image]